# Migrate data from one table to another table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What software do you use and recommend to easily import data from one database table to another database table?

Comment: Could do with more information really, are the tables the same, are they in different databases or on different servers?

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is pretty low on detail.  So, my answer may be overkill.  Or it may be just what the doctor ordered.  But you state in a prior comment you have "many tables".  It might be worth your time to learn how to use SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES (SSIS).

It can be intimidating at first... but once you get the hang of it, it's not too bad - and very powerful.

The following is a good tutorial to get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

This tutorial is also good:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tutorial.asp?tutorial=200

If that is way more than you need.  You might also try the Import/Export Wizard that comes in SQL Server Management Studio.

Right click on the database and look under Tasks for the "Import Data..." or "Export Data..." menu items.  This gives you a wizard that you can specify data from another database, or a single table, or a flat file etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use SQL Server for this?  It's incredibly easy, especially in later versions...

```
INSERT INTO MyTarget t
SELECT * FROM MySource s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTarget t2 WHERE t2.key = s.key)
```

You can also use an `EXCEPT` clause if you want to exclude certain data.

Comment: It would probably be doable with dynamic sql.